# Layouts look different on devices

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, textview

My hardware:

- Google Glass(screen density=1.5, resolution 640*360px)
- Vuzix M100(screen density=0.75, resolution 432*244px)

Here's how my layout looks like on Google Glass:

[image]

and on Vuzix:

[image]

**Layout source:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_secondary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_padding">
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/separator_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/separator_margin_top"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_instructions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/instruction_sign_in"
            android:textSize="@dimen/instructions_text_size" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/container_primary_padding_left" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
<dimen name="activity_margin">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="separator_width">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="separator_margin_top">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="separator_margin_bottom">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="instructions_text_size">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="layout_padding">3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="medium_text_size">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="small_text_size">22sp</dimen>
<dimen name="almost_large_text_size">50sp</dimen>
<dimen name="large_text_size">60sp</dimen>
<dimen name="huge_text_size">100sp</dimen>
<dimen name="container_primary_padding_left">10dp</dimen>
```

**Source for right layout section:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_row_label"
        android:id="@+id/tv_destination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="AA"
        android:textSize="@dimen/huge_text_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see all values are density-independent. But layouts still look different. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do your devices have a different physical size?

Comment: @FD_ they have a projector screens, so I can't really tell.

Comment: Hey @IgorFilippov : how have you developd for Google Glass and Vuzix m100 ? have you used different sdks ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your devices have a different physical size. This might not be visible due to the screens being projected, but it's the only possible reason.

Density-independent means your widgets share the same physical size between different screen densities. Be it an hdpi or and ldpi device, what you want to be XX dp in size is YY cm on any device.

Now, as you have devices that differ in physical size, you see bigger spaces between your widgets on one device because its screen is bigger. While the widgets have the same physical size as on the other device, there is more empty space left.

One solution would be to use a `TextView` that automatically adjusts the text size on the space it has available, such as [this one](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with separate dimensions for normal and small screens.